# Are the two topologies generated by the sets different?

Tags: general-topology

I saw this question in Munkres but cant find an answer for it.
Let $B$ be a set defined by the following:
$$B:\{[a,b): a,b  \text { are rational}\}$$
So is the topology generated by this set different from the topology generated by the lower limit topology on $\Bbb{R}$. How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the lower limit topology, $\pi$ has the neighbourhood $U = [\pi, 4)$. In the topology generated by $B$, there is no neighbourhood of $\pi$ that is contained in $U$. Therefore, the lower limit topology is strictly finer than this $B$-generated topology.

Comment: I am such an idiot I wasn't able to think about this much

Comment: @Rememberme I assume that's why your question was downvoted and voted to close as well. Some people downvote automatically when they see a question without any of the asker's own thoughts, and the vote-to-close $\to$ off-topic $\to$ missing context is made for exactly that situation.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Yes, it's different. Show that if $\alpha$ is irrational, $[\alpha,\to)$ is open in the lower limit topology but not in the topology generated by $B$. (You may be more used to the notation $[\alpha, \infty)$.)